# I don't have Siri enabled but get Siri suggestions in iOS 12

Tags: iphone, siri, ios

I've disabled Siri years ago, before updating to iOS 11 and now iOS 12 on my iPhone 6S. So I don't have **Siri & Search** in my Settings, but I do get Siri suggestions on my lock screen after a missed call (after updating to iOS 12).

How can I get rid of the Siri suggestions on my lock screen and why do they appear if Siri is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable theses suggestions by going into Settings > Siri & Search and switching "On lockscreen" off.
As to why this isn't normally disabled if you disable Siri, I don't know.

Comment: Like I said in my post, I don't have "Siri & Search" in Settings.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. I didn't know that was even possible. You did you disable Siri and can you enable it again? If not, I would suggest resetting all settings in the general settings.

Comment: I dread resetting all settings, but i will have to at some point. thanks.